# Actuator dependency doesn't display the health of some application

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-actuator

I developped an application spring-boot, I use spring-boot-starter-actuator to have the information about my application. THe problem is that the request GET: /health dosn't display the state of redis.  This is a snapshot of my application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://********
    username: ****
    password: *******
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  ldap:
    urls: ldap://*****
    username: ****
    password: *******
  redis:
    url: redis://******
```

this is the result of making a GET request ot:  /health

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "diskSpace": {
        "status": "UP"
    },
    "ldap": {
        "status": "UP",
        "version": "3"
    },
    "db": {
        "status": "UP",
        "database": "MySQL",
        "hello": 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems Spring Actuator does not recognize the Redis is enable. Could you add this config to you yml file

```
management:
  health:
    redis:
      enabled: true
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks @Kenny Tai Huynh I tried you suggestion but it doesn't work

Comment: Still the same issue?! Can you double-check the config in yml file?! Is there any space or sth?! Or
 try to enable all: management.health.defaults.enabled = true. According this "Auto-configured HealthIndicators": https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html . I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and I found the solution.

Well if you take a look at the default class `RedisHealthIndicator` from spring-boot-actuator you will notice that it uses

```
private final RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;
```

to actually connect to the Redis server and check the status. However, this class is imported from `import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;`

So as long as you don't use `spring-data-redis` in your project the out-of-the-box health indicator doesn't work. Just as a curiosity because I really don't want to import spring-data-redis I added it as a dependency in my project and the health indicator appeared if in `application.properties` I setup this:

```
 management.health.redis.enabled = true
```

Took out the dependency and the health endpoint disappeared.

In conclusion, to have the Redis health indicator in the spring boot actuator health you either need to use spring-data-redis and enable the default Redis health indicator or create your own by simply extending the `AbstractHealthIndicator` and check the state yourself. I think I will try the second option - it doesn't seem too hard.

**Edit - I did it, and it works like a charm**. I just created a class that extends `AbstractHealthIndicator` and in the `doHealthCheck` method I simply do this:

```
@Override
protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception {
    var pong = healthConnection.sync().ping();
    if (pong.equals("PONG")) {
        builder.up();
    }
}
```

I use io.lettuce:lettuce-core for the Redis connection. The connection is setup in constructor and closed on a `@PreDestroy` method.

Now in health endpoint I get: `{"status":"UP","details":{"redis":{"status":"UP"},"db":{"status":"UP","details":{"database":"MySQL","hello":1}}}}`